# Creating bins from dates

Tags: r

I have the following data:

[image]

I am trying to take that data and create the following format:

[image]

The idea that I would bin the dates in the predicted_forecast_date into four days and take the average temperature of it. That would lead to four columns being added for each bin of four dates.

[image]

Any suggestions on how I could accomplish this with R?

EDIT TO ADD MORE DATA:

```
created_forecast_date,predicted_forecast_date,daily_avg_temp
10/7/17,10/7/17,51.16868
10/7/17,10/8/17,62.60385
10/7/17,10/9/17,60.01031
10/7/17,10/10/17,59.02917
10/7/17,10/11/17,47.96719
10/7/17,10/12/17,45.26833
10/7/17,10/13/17,47.89635
10/7/17,10/14/17,55.4725
10/7/17,10/15/17,43.23625
10/7/17,10/16/17,37.19208
10/7/17,10/17/17,42.74482
10/7/17,10/18/17,40.49875
10/7/17,10/19/17,41.7275
10/7/17,10/20/17,41.88375
10/7/17,10/21/17,42.08875
10/7/17,10/22/17,43.45625
10/8/17,10/8/17,62.45715
10/8/17,10/9/17,59.4224
10/8/17,10/10/17,61.53281
10/8/17,10/11/17,48.98281
10/8/17,10/12/17,49.08937
10/8/17,10/13/17,47.71719
10/8/17,10/14/17,56.45708
10/8/17,10/15/17,42.81
10/8/17,10/16/17,44.59833
10/8/17,10/17/17,50.08292
10/8/17,10/18/17,41.28101
10/8/17,10/19/17,41.775
10/8/17,10/20/17,47.6075
10/8/17,10/21/17,50.31375
10/8/17,10/22/17,54.40625
10/8/17,10/23/17,50.16125
10/8/17,10/24/17,50.08625
```

And attempted the command below - hope it is relevant. It is a much larger data set - but was trying to keep it simple.

```
dput(head(DailyAverages))
structure(list(created_forecast_date = structure(c(17446, 17446, 
17446, 17446, 17446, 17446), class = "Date"), predicted_forecast_date = structure(c(17446, 
17447, 17448, 17449, 17450, 17451), class = "Date"), daily_avg_temp = c(51.1686805555556, 
62.6038541666667, 60.0103125, 59.0291666666667, 47.9671875, 45.2683333333333
), daily_min_temp = c(41.195, 57.015, 54.7475, 52.83, 41.1975, 
36.3125), daily_max_temp = c(64.48, 67.19, 65.0025, 68.43, 54.84, 
57.9875), daily_avg_dew_point = c(43.2444444444444, 59.1958333333333, 
57.2585416666667, 54.3040625, 35.4146875, 34.0580208333333), 
    daily_min_dew_point = c(38.21, 51.26, 54.2025, 46.275, 32.315, 
    31.895), daily_max_dew_point = c(50.9325, 64.125, 59.4, 58.595, 
    43.015, 38.61), daily_avg_pressure = c(1019.49972222222, 
    1009.33604166667, 1013.826875, 1013.21354166667, 1023.82, 
    1030.55802083333), daily_min_pressure = c(1015.5475, 1003.29, 
    1008.15, 1012.1925, 1016.535, 1028.54), daily_max_pressure = c(1021.97333333333, 
    1015.44, 1016.66, 1015.2775, 1028.4825, 1032.4875), daily_avg_ground_pressure = c(992.186770833333, 
    982.6509375, 986.999375, 986.559270833333, 996.352083333333, 
    1002.77677083333), daily_min_ground_pressure = c(988.4975, 
    976.5325, 981.6625, 985.6275, 989.6175, 1001.425), daily_max_ground_pressure = c(994.4, 
    988.3075, 989.88, 988.5125, 1000.9675, 1004.3725), daily_avg_humidity = c(76.0541666666667, 
    88.814375, 90.9704166666667, 86.1204166666667, 62.5190625, 
    66.6915625), daily_avg_clouds = c(20.4097222222222, 84.90625, 
    67.21875, 40.5416666666667, 9.78125, 10.8020833333333), daily_avg_wind_speed = c(6.20059027777778, 
    11.9998958333333, 5.4228125, 4.80208333333333, 8.73354166666667, 
    3.544375), daily_avg_rain = c(0, 11.8425, 0.5625, 0.3825, 
    0, 0), daily_avg_accumulated = c(0, 11.8425, 0.5625, 0.3825, 
    0, 0)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -6L), groups = structure(list(created_forecast_date = structure(17446, class = "Date"), 
    .rows = structure(list(1:6), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -1L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Comment: Hi user1453561! Can you include some of your data in your question (the function dput() helps ! :-)

Comment: I think this is a rolling-window question, but it's not clear how exactly the windows are defined, when I see `created_forecast_date` and `predicted_fo...` with various spans between them. Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly into a [code block].

Comment: Hi everyone - sorry for the poorly written question. I am going to attempt with the answer below. I am really new to R - so I wasn't sure how to include that data. To explain more about the data - it is historical 16 day forecast data. For example - the created_forecast column is the day the 16 day forecast was created. So each forecast_date should have 16 days of future predictions.  I will try to figure out how to provide sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach that adds a 4 day grouping with `cut`, then widens the data with `pivot_wider`. Using toy data.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(grp = paste0("timespan", consecutive_id(cut(predicted_forcast_date, 
    breaks=seq(min(predicted_forcast_date), 
               max(predicted_forcast_date), 4))), "_avg_temp"), 
    .by = created_forcast_date) %>% 
  summarize(value = mean(daily_avg_temp), 
    .by = c(created_forcast_date, grp)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from=grp, values_from=value)
```

output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 5
  created_forcast_day timespan1_avg_temp timespan2_avg_temp timespan3_avg_temp
  <date>                           <dbl>              <dbl>              <dbl>
1 2017-10-07                        54.3               53.0               53.7
2 2017-10-08                        57.0               54.8               52.2
# ℹ 1 more variable: timespan4_avg_temp <dbl>
```

##### Data

```
set.seed(42)

df <- data.frame(
  created_forcast_date = c(rep(as.Date("2017-10-07"), 16), rep(as.Date("2017-10-08"), 16)), 
  predicted_forcast_date = rep(seq(as.Date("2017-10-08"), as.Date("2017-10-23"), 1), 2), 
  daily_avg_temp = 40 + runif(32) * 30)
```

Comment: Thank you - I will give this a go and report back!